# is it important to put the google tag manager codes in website head tag

Tags: html, google-tag-manager

i have the google tag manager codes:

```html
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5K4WCTR');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

google recommendation is :
Copy the code below and paste it onto every page of your website.
Paste this code as high in the  of the page as possible.

so my concern is can i put the codes in website footer just before closing body tag. does putting it in head affect the google page speed score and what are the cons if i do so.
share your knowledge and experience please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Experience is anecdotal so take this with a grain of salt.

We A/B tested GTM positions in a major (> 17m sessions/month) website and found no real difference in the outcome between positioning it in the header or footer, which we found surprising, since we had expected data loss (that is the reason Google suggests to put the code as high as possible).

Moving GTM did not affect overall loading time (since the amount of assets loaded was the same), but it did speed up the time before the users could interact with the page.

Moving GTM helped us to save a few events; there was some data that we had to take from existing markup or variables on the page. Before we had to send an event at DOM ready, after the move we could send the same data as custom dimensions with the pageview (this is a workaround, however, ideally all necessary data would be pushed on the datalayer).

This does not mean that I think GTM can be placed safely at the page bottom in all cases; I assume the more stuff you load in your page, the more likely it is that a user cancels loading before GTM is executed. But it does mean I do not think an absolute prohibition of having the code in the footer makes sense, the only way to know for sure is to test both.

Answer (score 4):

Google recommends putting it immediately inside of the head and not inside of any other html element. Why? It’s better for tracking all around. The higher up in the page the snippet is, the faster it is loaded. In the older version of Google Tag Manager, it was recommended to place the snippet in the body tag, but this would potentially miss tracking users who left your page before the body tag loaded.

This has become even more important with the release of Google’s new A/B testing tool, Optimize. Whether you’re running a redirect test or and A/B experiment, having the snippet load faster ensures that Optimize will load the correct version of the page that your user is supposed to see, as soon as possible.